# USRP - daughterboard installation issue

Tags: usrp

I'm trying to receive a signal whith a center frequency equal to 2e8Hz and a bandwith slightly smaller than 2e5Hz with my USRP X310.
I use the rx_sampletofile.cpp func of uhd 3.10.1 as shown :

```
./rx_sampletofile --file test.bin --duration --rate 4e8 --nsamps 4e8 1 --freq 2e8 --type float --bw 8e7 --skip-lo
```

When I look at the terminal, everything is executed without error or warnings but I see that the actual rx frequency isn't changed afterall ...

```
Setting RX Rate: 20.000000 Msps...
Actual RX Rate: 20.000000 Msps...

Setting RX Freq: 200.000000 MHz...
Setting RX LO Offset: 0.000000 MHz...
Actual RX Freq: 0.000000 MHz...

Setting RX Bandwidth: 0.250000 MHz...
Actual RX Bandwidth: 0.250000 MHz...
```

I tried to change RX Freq to lower freq and also--lo-offset but it always stays at RX Freq = 0Hz so if you have any idea I'll take it.

Thanks

It appears that my issue is finally related to the daughterboards because the drivers don't detect them well.
Daughterboard Issue :

```
         _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX Dboard: A
|   |   |   ID: Unknown (0x0095)
|   |   |   Serial: 31F94F3
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Frontend: 0
|   |   |   |   Name: Unknown (0x0095) - 0
|   |   |   |   Antennas:
|   |   |   |   Sensors:
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 0.000 to 0.000 MHz
|   |   |   |   Gain Elements: None
|   |   |   |   Bandwidth range: 0.0 to 0.0 step 0.0 Hz
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Codec: A
|   |   |   |   Name: ads62p48
|   |   |   |   Gain range digital: 0.0 to 6.0 step 0.5 dB
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX Dboard: B
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Frontend: 0
|   |   |   |   Name: Unknown (0xffff) - 0
|   |   |   |   Antennas:
|   |   |   |   Sensors:
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 0.000 to 0.000 MHz
|   |   |   |   Gain Elements: None
|   |   |   |   Bandwidth range: 0.0 to 0.0 step 0.0 Hz
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Codec: B
|   |   |   |   Name: ads62p48
|   |   |   |   Gain range digital: 0.0 to 6.0 step 0.5 dB
|   |     _____________________________________________________
```

Comment: do you mean `rx_samples_to_file`? There's no `rx_sampletofile` as far as I can tell, and especially there's no `rx_sampletofile` func(tion). Also, 250 kHz is a bandwidth that none of the daughterboards of a X310 can do. Also, you forgot to specify a sampling rate. Also, please don't use random tags. I'm correcting your tags.

Comment: Please tell us exactly which USRP and which daughterboards you're using.

Comment: I have two TwinRX-80 USRP DBOARD

Comment: I didn't write the complete command line but I gave a sampling rate, "--skip-lo" and nsamps parameters. I thought that it was not the things causing my issue so I prefered not to put extra details sorry !

Comment: Another student installed uhd drivers on my computer so it is possible that he miss something. I have rx_sampletofile instead of rx_samples_to_file that is everywhere on the Internet but I thought it was supposed to do the same as the args parameters and documentation were identical.

Comment: I thought that 250 kHz was ok since it's lower than 80 MHz...
Thank you Marcus for your help !

Comment: I eddited my post to "update" my real problem. I'll try to fix it on my own but if someone has a solution for my new problem, I will also read it so feel free to comment !

Answer (score 0):

Your UHD is too old for your hardware revision of the TwinRX daughterboard.

The only solution is to use a more modern version of UHD. This will also require you to load a more modern version of the FPGA image.

Comment: Yes that is what I feared, I will have to reinstall uhd then !
I have not enough reputation to upvote your answer but I think it's the best solution to my issue.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: you're the asker: you don't have to upvote, you can accept ;)